# Error while executing gem...Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, rubygems, overriding, taps

I am attempting to install taps from my Heroku app folder. When I type "gem install taps," I get the following error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied - /Users/jacob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/taps-0.3.24/bin/taps

I attempted to remove the taps-0.3.24 folder using rm -r and got this question: override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for /Users/jacob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/taps-0.3.24//bin/schema?

Upon typing yes, it tells me permission denied. Here is the whole exchange:

> Jacob-MacBook-Pro:furious-ocean-6122012 jacob$ rm -r /Users/jacob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/taps-0.3.24/
>   override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for /Users/jacob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/taps-0.3.24//bin/schema? yes
>   rm: /Users/jacob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/taps-0.3.24//bin/schema: Permission denied
>   override rw-r--r--  root/staff for /Users/jacob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/taps-0.3.24//bin/schema.cmd?

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this when trying to get the Heroku Toolbelt running. I was able to remove the old version with `sudo rm -rf /path/to/gems/taps-x.x.x` and then re-install (without sudo).

Answer (score 0):

You should add "sudo" before "gem...."