# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: rubygems, rvm

```
$ gem install passenger
Fetching: passenger-4.0.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195 directory.
$ ls -ld /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
drwxrwsr-x  8 root  rvm  272 21 May 16:07 /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
```

Clearly my version of ruby is owned by root/rvm.

I'm not happy with this SO answer which suggests making .gem/specs world-writable:
[Permission denied error with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303088/permission-denied-error-with-rvm)

and this SO answer is for a specific gem:
[Error while executing gem...Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003808/error-while-executing-gem-permission-denied)

Any better suggestions?

Perhaps repair permissions / ownership on the .rvm directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RVM has a command to fix permissions:

```
rvm get head
rvm fix-permissions
```

Comment: how this solution helped solving the FilePermissionError?

Comment: `rvm fix-permissions` resets access to all files / directories within RVM directory structure - and all gems are installed in `$rvm_path/gems/...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take ownership of the .rvm directory with something like:

```
sudo chown -R groupname:username /Users/username/.rvm
```

Where username is your user login name. The groupname is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Using the principle of Less Complexity, the obvious answer was:

```
sudo gem install passenger
```

If you start using `rvm` or `rbenv` then you start going down the path of additional complexity.

Then you start running into all the problems they create.