# Why do I get "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)"?

Tags: ruby, permissions, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I [uninstalled RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/howto-uninstall-rvm) and re-installed using a [single user installation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) using:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

When I do `bundle`, it prompts for:

```
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:
```

I tried using the answer in "[ERROR: While executing gem … (Gem::FilePermissionError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248872/error-while-executing-gem-gemfilepermissionerror)" which did not fix it.

Then, while trying to install the gem manually, I got:

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

then running   `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` returned:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

I checked all the similar posts on SO, but they didn't solve the problem. What am I missing?

Comment: From your error message (nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.) you have an older Ruby version. Check your Ruby version.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me fix the problem! After updating the ruby version, I had to do few manual gem installs. Write it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you install RVM you still need few more steps:

1. Load RVM to the current shell:

   ```
   source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
   ```

   Usually this would not be needed if you close and open your terminal again
2. Install ruby:

   ```
   rvm install ruby
   ```
3. Use ruby:

   ```
   rvm use ruby
   ```

The last step is very important as your error message mentioned system ruby not the one controlled by RVM.

Comment: \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable. run this comment before run the script rvm.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time fixing this issue on my MacBook. The `gem update --system` does not work for me.

At last, putting the following code in the `~/.zshrc` file and create a new zsh session works for me.

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
export GEM_PATH="$HOME/.gem"
```

Comment: Boom! works like magic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your system rubygems with this command : `sudo gem update --system --no-user-install`.

**bundler** use it instead your local version and your bundler version could be incompatible with your system rubygems.

It works for me ;)

Comment: This solved an identical error I was getting via rbenv. Thanks!